# Dialog using Toplevel windows in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have written some Tkinter dialogs that are called from within an app running in a mainloop. My dialog initializer usually looks like this:

```
class OKCANCEL( Toplevel ):
    def __init__( self, parent, title ):
        Toplevel.__init__( self, parent )
        self.parent = parent
        self.title( title )
...
```

I call this from within my app as:

```
o = OKCANCEL( self.mainWindow, mtext = QUIT_REALLY )
```

where `self.mainWindow`is a Frame within my App window (a class inheriting from Frame).
Now, every time that I am calling the dialog, a smaller window appears and **then** the intended window replaces the small one. The display duration is short, however, it is annoying to have this appening.
Am I missing the obvious?
Can someone point me to my mistake?

Thanks!

Edit: I just wrote up a small example and tried to reproduced the behaviour, however, either it was not present or it happened too fast. I am kind of confused, the small window that appears even has a window title that is nowhere to be found in the code (the big, huge chunk of code that is not on this page).

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import os
from Tkinter import *

class WARNING(Toplevel): #ok only dialog
       def __init__(self,parent,wtext,wtitle=''):
            Toplevel.__init__(self,parent)
            self.parent=parent
            self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",self._NULL) #we need to include a check again...
            self.title(wtitle)
            self.attributes('-topmost',True)
            self.transient()
            mainWindow=Frame(self)
            tFrame=Frame(mainWindow)
            tLabel=Label(tFrame,text=wtext,height=3,bd=10)
            tLabel.pack()
            bFrame=Frame(mainWindow,bd=5)
            bOK=Button(bFrame,bd=1,text='Ok',command=self._DONE)
            bOK.pack(side='left')
            tFrame.grid(row=0,column=0)
            bFrame.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=E)
            mainWindow.pack()

        def _DONE(self,Event=None):
            self.destroy()

        def _NULL():
            pass

    class WarnApp(Frame):

        def __init__(self,parent):
            Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            self.parent=parent
            self.initUI()

        def initUI(self):
            self.parent.title("Warning test")
            self.mainWindow = Frame(self.parent)
            B1=Button(self.mainWindow,command=self.Warn,text='Warn-Me')
            B1.pack(fill=BOTH)
            self.mainWindow.pack(fill=BOTH)
            self.pack(fill=BOTH)

        def Warn(self):
            warn=WARNING(self,wtext='This is a warning',wtitle='generic warning dialog')
            self.wait_window(warn)

    def main():
        root=Tk()
        app = WarnApp(root)
        app.mainloop()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
    `
```

Comment: Can you give us a small, complete working example that has this problem? Tkinter won't do this unless you tell it to, so we need to see what else you are doing.

Comment: Are you calling `update` while creating the dialog? Maybe this little window is just the dialog before it has widgets in it. Unfortunately, if you can't duplicate it, neither can we.

Comment: After editing so code runs, I do not see problem either.  In code that did, it might help to change parent to root, as in changing `warn=WARNING(self,` to `warn=WARNING(self.parent,`